# how can i solve this issue that prompt up when i run 'npm run develope' after installing strapi?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

it's my first time of working with strapi, first i created my first strapi dashboard
using  :

`npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart`

After that i filled in the form which took me to my strapi dashboard. Now i want to customise and insall new strapi for my project following a video instruction i am watch and i used :

`npx create-strapi-app@latest .`

i run the following command during the installation :

`PS C:\Users\Cullkid\Desktop\shopping\api> npx create-strapi-app@latest . ? Choose your installation type Custom (manual settings) ? Choose your preferred language (Use arrow keys) ? Choose your preferred language JavaScript ? Choose your default database client ? Choose your default database client mysql ? Database name: store ? Database name: store ? Host: (127.0.0.1) ? Host: 127.0.0.1 ? Port: (3306) ? Port: 3306 ? Username: root ? Username: root ? Password: ********* ? Password: ********* ? Enable SSL connection: (y/N) n ? Enable SSL connection: No`

The installion was successful but i got this error when i run npm run develop which suppose to take me to my dashboad

``api@0.1.0 develop`
strapi develop

Building your admin UI with development configuration...
Admin UI built successfully
[2023-02-15 23:39:26.496] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2023-02-15 23:39:26.503] error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does no
t support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading M
ySQL client
Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication p
rotocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
at Sequence._packetToError
`

i tried to run npm run develop that should take me to my strapi dashboard but it feld

Answer (score 0):

At the root of the project:

1. `npm uninstall mysql`
2. `npm install mysql2`
3. open `.env` file and change `DATABASE_CLIENT=mysql` to `DATABASE_CLIENT=mysql2`
4. rerun `npm run develop`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

At the root of the project:
like where node modules are:

npm uninstall mysql
npm install mysql2
open .env file and change DATABASE_CLIENT=mysql to DATABASE_CLIENT=mysql2
rerun npm run develop